# How can we maintain ordering at the consumer level in Kafka, Azure Service bus?

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, azureservicebus

The problem is that we have a consumer reading from a queue and that consumer doing some updates to the database. Now we need to run multiple instances of the same consumer to help with the load.

instance A, instance B, and instance C are the running instances of the same consumer, and both of them are reading from the same queue. the messages on the queue are already in order.

For example, suppose I produced 3 messages in its respective order M1, M2, M3 to a single queue Q1.

M1:

{"userId": 1, "favourite_food": "chicken"}
M2:

{"userId": 1, "favourite_food": "beef"}
M3:

{"userId": 1, "favourite_food": "fish"}

with this messages order the last value of the favourit_update should be "fish".
**
But**
**The processing time is different from one instance to the other.**

Instance A will read the M1, B will read M2, and C will read M3.

A will process the message in t+2 to make the value of the favourite_food =Chicken.
B will process the message in t+10 to make the value of the favourite_food =beef.
C will process the message in t+2 to make the value of the favourite_food =fish.

But because instance B takes more time (t+10) to process the message, The result will be "beef" as favourit_food.

How can we make sure that the DB updates will be in the same sequence as the messages in the queue?

I have don't haveany  idea about how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample messages you provided, I assume serial processing is scoped to a specific user (userId), in which case you shouldn't really be parallel processing the messages anyway.

In Azure Service Bus, you can use [Message Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) which ensure messages with the same `SessionId` are processed serially, which in your case should be set to the `userId`.

With this, you can still have multiple consumers to share the load but the messages for a particular `userId` will be processed by a single consumer serially.